# Uses of その他/他に(も)/他(に)は

Tags: grammar, meaning

I’m currently studying tobira and in ch9 there is this sentence

> 「浪人」というのは、もともと「主人のいない侍」のことを意味したが、今は希望の大学に入れなかったために予備校に行ったりしながら受験勉強をしている人達
> のことを指す。**その他**、受験の厳しさを表す言葉には「四当五落」や「試験地獄」という表現もある。

I understand that the use of that その他 is “in addition to” from the context, but according to Tobira’s ch3 it has to be either ~他に(も) or  ~他(に)は to mean "in addition to/besides". My question is, is it possible for a regular その他 to have the meaning of “in addition to/besides”?

Comment: Could you show the preceding sentence as well? It could be useful for context.

Comment: @JansthcirlU I have added the preceding sentence. The paragraph in general is about the difficulties (and kind of negative aspects) of the Japanese educational system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sentence adverb, その他 does not have much difference with 他に. They both mean that the upcoming sentence is a supplement/digression. It however does not equal 他に**は／も** because the additional topic particle suggests that the sentence has something to do with the main context in some way ("what's more" etc).

> その他、受験の厳しさを表す言葉には……もある
> 他に、受験の厳しさを表す言葉には……もある
> "As something else, there are more words that illustrate the bitterness of entry exams, ..."
> ≈ *Other words that illustrate the bitterness of entry exams include...*

Note that その他 is mostly an adverb while 他【ほか】 as such is a **noun** ("other people/place/thing..."), and not interchangeable when it is used as a plain noun.

> 他に（× その他）迷惑をかけないでほしい
> *I'd rather you don't bother the others.*

Comment: You say that その他 is similar with 他に but not with他には／も, but with その他 and 他に being a supplement to the previous sentence doesn’t that mean that they are also related with the main context?

Comment: @HarothSilph I meant that it is "as an aside" information rather than being incorporated in the flow of main context or argument, as a supporting evidence or anything. Welcome for any suggestion for better English though...

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. The differences where kind of subtle so it was hard to get a full understanding of it.